# Is there a way to suppress extraction progress window for exe created by 7zip?

Tags: powershell, cmd, 7zip

I am calling an exe CS.exe using powershell. It shows progress bar.

```
&"$Path\CS.exe" -o"$OutputPath" -y | Out-Null
```

Is there any way to suppress this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a PowerShell progress bar, you can suppress it by setting the `$ProgressPreference` variable to `SilentlyContinue`:

```
# When set to SilentlyContinue, Progress bars will be supressed
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
```

---

If the progress bar you're seeing is stderr output written by the executable, you can suppress it with cmd-style output redirection (all versions):

```
&"$Path\CS.exe" -o"$OutputPath" -y >$null 2>&1
```

Or with stream redirection (PowerShell version 3.0 and above):

```
&"$Path\CS.exe" -o"$OutputPath" -y *>$null
```

You can read more about redirection: [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx)